# Linear ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have an first order ODE :

Equation1 :   $y' + y = x$  ? 
We can view the left-hand side as an operator acting on $y$.

In that case $L=(d/dx + 1)$

$L(y_1) = x$
$L(y_2)=x$
$L(y_1+y_2)=x$
So, clearly $L(y_1+y_2) = x \neq L(y_1)+L(y_2) = 2x$

So why is $y'+y=x$ is a linear ODE ?

Comment: Note that your $L$ is not correct. It should be $L(y)=y'+y$. And note that linearity requires more than additivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed earlier in another thread, the following
$$
L(y):=y'+y
$$
is a linear operator. Note it is not $y'+1$. And note that linear means
$$
L(\alpha y+ \beta z)=\alpha L(y)+ \beta L(z)
$$
for every scalars $\alpha,\beta$, and every differentiable functions $y,z$. The fact that $L$ is linear is merely the fact that differentiation is linear. What you wrote $L(y_1+y_2)=L(y_1)+L(y_2)$ does not suffice to claim linearity of $L$.

Now your ODE can be written
$$
L(y)=f
$$
with $f(x)=x$.

The solution set is either empty, or an affine subspace $$y_p+\ker L$$ where $y_p$ can be any particular solution. This is exactly like linear systems 
$$
AX=B
$$
where $A$ is a rectangular matrix. The solution set is either empty (the system is not compatible), or an affine subspace
$$
X_p+\ker A
$$
where $X_p$ is any particular solution.

People say linear to stress out the fact that there is a linear part in the equation which yields the affine structure of the solution set. One could also say that the equation is affine, by writing it $L(y)-f=0$ and observing that $y\longmapsto L(y)-f$ is affine. But nobody says that, as far as I know.

Comment: Let's go step by step, you said to prove the operator L is linear we need that L(αy1+βy2)=αL(y1)+βL(y2).Okay, do we know the value of αL(y1) and βL(y2) ? I think you would agree that they are αx and βx respectively, right ? Do we know the value of L(αy1+βy2) ? I think you would agree that it is x, right ? So by this fact we prove that x =/= (α+b)x  for every a and b  hence we prove that L(αy1+βy2) =/= αL(y1)+βL(y2) and that the operator L is not linear on the ODE.But i know the operator L is linear because it only differentiates.So,what's wrong in my logic, julien ?

Comment: @nerdy What's wrong is that considering $L(y)=y'+1$ does not make sense here. Instead, consider $L(y)=y'+y$, so that your equation reads $L(y)=f$. Since $f\neq 0$, the equation is not linear in the sense that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions, then, for instance, $y_1+y_2$ is not a solution. That's, if you want, because the operator $T:y\longmapsto L(y)-f=y'+y-f$ is not linear. But $L$ is linear, as $L(\alpha y_1+\beta y_2)=(\alpha y_1+\beta y_2)'+ \alpha y_1+\beta y_2=\alpha y_1'+\beta y_2'+\alpha y_1+\beta y_2=\alpha L(y_1)+\beta L(y_2)$.

Comment: I think i'm almost getting it. What i'm not getting is : We know that L(αy1+βy2) = αL(y1)+βL(y2) , right ? We also know that ODE makes L(y1)=L(y2)= f   right ?  It also makes L(αy1+βy2)=f as well, right ? So that would make  L(αy1+βy2) = αL(y1)+βL(y2)  turn into f = (a+b)f  . So this last equation will only hold if a+b=1, whats the meaning ? Does it mean that the ODE requires that the scalars of any two different solutions sum up to 1 ?

Comment: @nerdy No. This gives $(\alpha+\beta)f$, which is not $f$ in general.

Comment: What gives  (α+β)f ?

Comment: @nerdy For instance $\alpha=1=\beta$, then you get $2f\neq f$. It is therefore false that $L(y_1)=f$ and $L(y_2)=f$ implies $L(y_1+y_2)=f$.

Comment: Hmm i was thinking another thing to get the result L(y1+y2)=f. I thought like this.The ODE states that L is an operator that takes a generic function y and transforms it into f, no matter what y is.So i did, L(y1)=f, L(y2)=f ... and consdering y1+y2 as just only one function, L(y1+y2)=f.I thought the result of L operating on any function is f, no matter what function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7939/discussion-between-nerdy-and-julien)

Answer (score 1):

The equation is considered a linear differentail equation because the operator $1+\frac {d}{dx}$ is linear.  In this light $1+\frac {dy}{dx}y=f(x)$ is linear regardless of $x$.  This allows us to say that if we find any solution to the homogeneous part, the equation without the $f(x)$, we can add it to a solution of the whole equation and get another solution.

Comment: Try to solve my confusion, please.
L[y1] = y1' + y1 //
L[y2] = y2' + y2  //
right ?
L[y1+y2] = (y1+y2)' + y1 + y2 = L[y1] + L[y2] //
At the same time, by the ODE :
L[y] = x // 
So, L[y1]=L[y2]=x //
L[y1+y2] = x   as well so L[y1]+L[y2] =/= L[y1+y2]
//
Where is the error on my logic ?

Comment: The operator $y\longmapsto 1+y'$ is not linear. You have a typo, I think.

Comment: I see, you mean $L=Id+\frac{d}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve my confusion, please.

L[y1] = y1' + y1

L[y2] = y2' + y2

In this case :
L[y1+y2] = (y1+y2)' + y1 + y2 = L[y1] + L[y2]

At the same time, by the ODE :
L[y] = x

So, L[y1]=L[y2]=x
 L[y1+y2] = x as well

So, L[y1]+L[y2] =/= L[y1+y2]

Where is the error on my logic that finds both L[y1]+L[y2] =/= L[y1+y2]  and L[y1] + L[y2]  = L[y1+y2]       ?

Comment: This is not an answer. This should either be edited into the question or posed as a separate question.

Comment: Can you not edit this into the original question? If it does not fit there, then it should probably be asked as a separate question.

Comment: If you use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can do things like
$$
\begin{align}
L[y_1]&=y_1'+y_1\\
L[y_2]&=y_2'+y_2
\end{align}
$$
and so forth.